# helm template specific multiple value

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to declare in the _helpers.tpl file that a particular CRD is longer than 63 characters, and apply it to the CRD Name field.

I have configured CRDs to be N count created as shown in the values.yaml below, but when I put a "printf" function in _helpers.tpl or use it, I get an error.

What can I do to use it?

```
[valuesa.yaml]

common:
  info: 
    name: aaa
batchtemplate:
  - scheduler: 
      sacle: scale-out
  - scheduler: 
      sacle: scale-in
```

```
[workflow-crd.yaml]

{{- range $batch := .Values.batchtemplate }}
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: {{- include "server-peaktime-template.cron" $ }}.  <<-- error point
...
{{- end }}
```

```
[_helpers.tpl]

{{- define "server-peaktime-template.cron" -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" $.Values.common.info.name .scheduler.scale | replace "+" "_" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this

```
name A : <Values.common.info.name>-scale-out
Name B : <Values.common.info.name>-scale-in
```

Using both range and printf in helpers.tpl, but not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

In the Go `text/template` language that Helm uses, a template only takes a single parameter.  When you (Helm) `include` the template, the parameter you're passing is the top-level Helm object `$`.  Inside the `template`, `.` is that same object, so when you refer to `.scheduler.scale` it is not in the context of the `range` loop any more.

This specific helper template, as you've written it, seems very specific to the point you're invoking it.  The easiest approach might be to remove the helper template and put the `printf | ...` invocation directly in the calling code

```yaml
{{- range $batch := .Values.batchtemplate }}
metadata:
  name: {{- printf "%s-%s" $.Values.common.info.name .scheduler.scale | replace "+" "_" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
```

Another possible refactoring is to notice that you're taking two words and joining them with a hyphen.  You could use [`join`](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) (oddly not listed in the Helm documentation) to combine the list of words into a string, and if you did that then the list could be the single template parameter.  In turn, you can then use [`list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) to construct that parameter.  Again, within the helper template, `.` is the parameter (unless you use something like `range` or `with` that rebinds it).

```yaml
{{- define "server-peaktime-template.cron" -}}
{{- . | join "-" | replace "+" "_" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
```

```yaml
{{- range $batch := .Values.batchtemplate }}
metadata:
  name: {{- include "server-peaktime-template.cron" (list $.Values.common.info.name .scheduler.scale) }}
{{- end }}
```

(Also note that you have `.Release.Name`, the name passed in the `helm install` command, and `.Chart.Name`, from `Chart.yaml`, both available as parameters here.  The name construction you show conventionally uses these to construct the name, which would mean you don't need to separately mention it in the `values.yaml`.  Consider using `$.Release.Name` instead of `$.Values.common.info.name`.)